# Compare user input date to pandas df date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to compare user input date (month and year format) to pandas df date column and pick the corresponding value on the df.

here is an example:

```py
  birthDate = input("birth year-month?")
  deathDate = input("death year-month?")

  // assume that user inputs: 2-2022 and 3-2022

  df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['1-2022', '2-2022', '3-2022'],
                   'value': [1.4, 1223.22, 2323.23]})

   output:
   "birth day value is 1223.22"
   "death day value is 2323.23"
```

Comment: `s = df.set_index('date')['value']` then `s[x]` where `x` is the date to fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
birthDate = input("birth month-year?")
deathDate = input("death month-year?")

birthday_value = df.loc[df["date"] == birthDate, "value"].values[0]
deathday_value = df.loc[df["date"] == deathDate, "value"].values[0]

print(f"birth day value is {birthday_value}") 
print(f"death day value is {deathday_value}")
```

Output:

```
birth day value is 1223.22
death day value is 2323.23
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one -

```
print("birth day value is", float(df[df["date"]==birthDate]["value"]))
print("death day value is", float(df[df["date"]==deathDate]["value"]))
```